# How can I create a list view from the data of the list inside a list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

Error: "The argument type 'Breakfast' can't be assigned to the parameter type String. dart argument_type_not_assignable Breakfast ingredients"'. I dont know how to view the list inside a list.

```
   class BreakfastIngredient extends StatefulWidget {
      const BreakfastIngredient({
        Key? key,
      required this.breakfast,
      }) : super(key: key);

      final Breakfast breakfast;

      @override
     _BreakfastIngredientState createState() => _BreakfastIngredientState();
   }

   class _BreakfastIngredientState extends State<BreakfastIngredient> {
   
   late List ingredients;

   @override

   Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: breakfastProducts.map((ingredients){
        return  Text(ingredients);
        }
         ).toList()
     );  
    }
   }
```

'I am trying to get the data from this list'. I want to get the data from the "ingredients".

```
    List<Breakfast> breakfastProducts = [
     Breakfast(
      id: 1,
      images: [
        "assets/images/cilantro.png",
      ],
      title: "Cilantro and Kale Pesto Toast with a Fried Egg",
        time: 15,
        description: "Sliced bread is the perfect blank canvas, ready to be loaded up with virtuous ingredients.",
    rating: 4.8,
   isFavourite: true,
   isPopular: true,
   ingredients: [
        "¼ cup packed cilantro",
      "1 cup packed kale leaves",
       "¼ cup extra-virgin olive oil",
     "1 tablespoon white balsamic vinegar",
      "2 tablespoons hulled hemp seeds*",
      "salt",
        "Freshly ground pepper",
       "1 large slice of whole-wheat toast",
      "2 tablespoons unflavored whole-milk Greek yogurt",
       "1 fried egg",
   ],
   procedure: "procedure",
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Text widget accepts as parameters only a String, not  a List, one possible workaround is to join all ingredients into a single string:

```
   return Row(
      children: breakfastProducts.map((ingredients){
        return  Text(ingredients.join('\n'));
//Join every ingredient and insert a new line between each other
        }
         ).toList()
     );
```

A More performant approach would be to use a ListView to lazily create the Widgets, but depends on what you want to achieve :

```
   ListView.builder(
itemCount: breakfastProducts.ingredients.length   
,itemBuilder: (_,i)=>Text(breakfastProducts.ingredients[i])),
```

Full example:
Note that here you are working with a single Breakfast object

```
   class BreakfastIngredient extends StatefulWidget {
      const BreakfastIngredient({
        Key? key,
      required this.breakfast,
      }) : super(key: key);

      final Breakfast breakfast;

      @override
     _BreakfastIngredientState createState() => _BreakfastIngredientState();
   }

   class _BreakfastIngredientState extends State<BreakfastIngredient> {
   
   late List ingredients;

   @override

   Widget build (BuildContext context) {
final ingredients=widget.breakfast.ingredients;
return Text(ingredients.join("\n"));
   }
```

Comment: Error: The getter 'ingredients' isn't defined for the type 'List<Breakfast>'.

Comment: i don't know why it cant be accessed

Comment: if the image, there where no problem, but when the list of string, I can't get

Comment: I added a full example, but the widget takes a single `Breakfast` item as a parameter, it seems you're struggling to show a 'List<Breakfast>' and its corresponding ingredients. Is that the case? You want to display the ingredients list in the same page as all Breakfast, or with an ExpansionTilo, or maybe a detail page?

Comment: Hello I solved it just a few lines of code.

Comment: ```  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: widget.breakfast.ingredients.map((path) {
            return Text(
              "- " +path,
            );
          }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```

Comment: I use this " `widget.breakfast.ingredients.map((path) { return Text( "- " +path, ); }).toList(),` "